# problem encountering when setting up new facebook application

Tags: facebook, canvas

Hey,
I'm trying to built new facebook canvas FBML application.
my root directory on the server is: localhost/fbapp
and the page I want the canvas to display is index.php in this directory.
I defined:

site url: http://localhost/fbapp/
canvas url: http://localhost/fbapp/

when I went to the app page, I received the following error:

> App Temporarily Unavailable.
>   The URL http://localhost/fbapp/ is not valid.
>   Sorry, the application you were using
>   is experiencing a problem. Please try
>   again later.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs an external hostname, such as `http://daydreamerblog.com/fbapp/`.  `localhost` is an internal hostname only accessible from your local machine.  So, you'd need to run an external web server at, following the example domain name, `daydreamerblog.com` and use that address in your Facebook settings.